# How to enable magento 1.9.2.1 amazon affiliate check out

Tags: affiliate

How to enable amazon check out option in my admin panel magento ver 1.9.2.1?

Comment: Magento Extension : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/amazon-associates-affiliate-program.html

Comment: This is what i have purchased but i dont get the option for the checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Addul,says

Default *magento does not have this type of feature*.

You need to use **3-rd party extension**.

May be below extension  a reference for you requirement:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pay-with-amazon-for-magento.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-and-pay-with-amazon-advanced-payment-apis-for-europe.html

You can find lot of extension from magento connect: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=amazon&pl=0

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i purchase the AMAZON AFFILIATE extension and it says  this.   


"Advantages:


Send products from Magento shopping cart to Amazon Checkout with your Affiliate ID.

Answer (score 1):

Default magento not provided amazon affiliate check out option but you can use 3rd party extensions

Comment: i have purchased the third part extension but still i dont see the option.